# Seed data for test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I need to seed some geographical data for my test, and I'm not sure that I'm taking the right approach here, but here is how I've tried.

In my spec helper:

```
config.before(:each, location_data: true) do |example|
  address = FactoryGirl.create(:address, atitude: 20.9223, longitude: -72.551)
end
```

A specific address point I created. Then I have these, which I think are ruining my data :

```
config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

Then in my test I have this:

```
context 'nearby', location_data: true do
      context 'there should be 0 matches in radius' do
         binding.pry
         #When I debug here there are 0 addresses created
         expect(Address.count).to eq(1)
      end 
 end
```

When I look at the test log its like my test data setup is not even executed, what am I doing wrong here? I need this address for various tests, not just one but many complex scenarios and I would reuse the addresses in another tests, that's why I put them in a rspec config to make it more DRY

**Changes as suggested in max answer :**

```
module LocationData
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    let!(:address) { FactoryGirl.create(:address, latitude: 20.9223, longitude: -72.551) }
  end
end
```

Then in my test:

```
require 'support/location_data'

describe MyModel do
  include LocationData

  context 'nearby' do
      context 'there should be 1 matches in radius' do
         binding.pry
         #When I debug here there are 0 addresses created
         expect(Address.count).to eq(1)
      end 
  end
end
```

Still get 0 address count when I count addresses. Not sure what am I doing wrong.

**SOLUTION (thanks max):**

I was missing it block in context block :

```
context 'there should be 1 matches in radius' do
             binding.pry
             #When I debug here there are 0 addresses created
             it 'has one address before' do
               expect(Address.count).to eq(1)
             end
          end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good test suite will empty the database between each example.

**Why?** Stuffing a bunch of data into your database and then running some test on the same DB data sounds like a good idea at first. But if you tests alter that data than you soon end up with ordering issues which can cause flapping tests and serious headaches. Its an approach that has been tested and found lacking.

Instead you want a clean slate for each test. DatabaseCleaner does just that. It's not ruining your data - it's keeping your data from ruining your test suite and or sanity.

You never want to create test data in your rspec configuration. Use it to setup the tools you need to run your test. If you start creating a bunch of flags to set up data from your config it's going to get out of control quickly. And you don't really need the exact same data as often as you think.

Instead if you find yourself repeatedly setting up the same data in your specs you can dry it out with example groups. Or create named factories with FactoryGirl.

```
module GeocodedExampleGroup
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    let(:address) { FactoryGirl.create(:address, latitude: 20.9223, longitude: -72.551) }
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'support/example_groups/geocoded'

describe SomeModel do
  include GeocodedExampleGroup

  # ...
end
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation, and for example, but I could not get it to work, I ll update my question with what i've done.